# How to transpose a string column of excel data into a list?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Data File Imported from Excel

| Trans ID | Trans Name | B ID | B Name | B Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 707 | Mr Person Co | 679 | Mr Perceval Person | Borrower |
| 707 | Mr Person Co | 7777 | Ms Patricia Person | Guarantor |
| 708 | Mr Doe Co | 222 | Mr John Doe | Guarantor |
| 708 | Mr Doe Co | 2553 | Mrs Jane Doe | Principal |

I would like it to come out looking like this:

| Trans ID | Trans Name | B ID | B Name | B Role | G Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 707 | Mr Person Co | 679, 7777 | Mr Perceval Person, Ms Patricia Person | Borrower | Guarantor |
| 708 | Mr Doe Co | 222, 2553 | Mr John Doe, Mrs Jane Doe | _ | Guarantor |

NOTE:

1. There are multiple B ID's for one Trans ID.
2. There are multiple B Roles for one B Name
3. There are multiple type of roles under B Role, I would like to separate each role into their own  column according to the role of the corresponding B Name.

I would like to keep all the duplicates but most of the solutions I have run into do not work on the B Name because it is a string and I don't know how to get around this problem. I have attempted to use pandas groupby and join lists and haven't quite gotten a satisfactory solution. Any solution or advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome.. Please provide us with minimum reproducible example and also share your code with us...

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? Why is Borrower under B Role and Guarantor under G Role? Why is "Principal" missing from the output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As I previously mentioned there are multiple roles under B role that I would like to separate and be housed in their own column. Principal is missing from the output because it would be in its own column under P Role. This is my first Q so when I ran out of space for the table I just assumed it would be inferred. So sorry for not being clear.

Comment: Could you specify what code your looking for because right now none of my codes have provided the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can split this into 2 parts and merge together the strings and roles.

The function `string` just joins the strings in the groups by the delimiter.

```py
def string(x):
    return ",\n".join(x.astype(str))

# ID and Name to string
strings = df.groupby(["Trans ID", "Trans Name"],
                     as_index=True).agg(
                         {"B ID": string, "B Name": string})

# roles to columns
role_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df.set_index(["Trans ID", "Trans Name"])
                              ["B Role"]) \
    .groupby(["Trans ID", "Trans Name"]).max()

# fill with role
role_dummies = role_dummies.where(role_dummies!=1,
                                  role_dummies.columns.to_series(),
                                  axis=1)

out = pd.merge(strings, role_dummies, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```